# TomEE chokes on too many @Asynchronous operations

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, apache-tomee

I am using Apache TomEE 1.5.2 JAX-RS, pretty much out of the box, with the predefined HSQLDB.

The following is simplified code. I have a REST-style interface for receiving signals:

```
@Stateless
@Path("signal")
public class SignalEndpoint {
    @Inject
    private SignalStore store;

    @POST
    public void post() {
        store.createSignal();
    }
}
```

Receiving a signal triggers a lot of stuff. The store will create an entity, then fire an asynchronous event.

```
public class SignalStore {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    private EventDispatcher dispatcher;

    @Inject
    private Event<SignalEntity> created;

    public void createSignal() {
        SignalEntity entity = new SignalEntity();
        em.persist(entity);
        dispatcher.fire(created, entity);
    }
}
```

The dispatcher is very simple, and merely exists to make the event handling asynchronous.

```
@Stateless
public class EventDispatcher {
    @Asynchronous
    public <T> void fire(Event<T> event, T parameter) {
        event.fire(parameter);
    }
}
```

Receiving the event is something else, which derives data from the signal, stores it, and fires another asynchronous event:

```
@Stateless
public class DerivedDataCreator {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    private EventDispatcher dispatcher;

    @Inject
    private Event<DerivedDataEntity> created;

    @Asynchronous
    public void onSignalEntityCreated(@Observes SignalEntity signalEntity) {
        DerivedDataEntity entity = new DerivedDataEntity(signalEntity);
        em.persist(entity);
        dispatcher.fire(created, entity);
    }
}
```

Reacting to that is even a third layer of entity creation.

To summarize, I have a REST call, which synchronously creates a `SignalEntity`, which asynchronously triggers the creation of a `DerivedDataEntity`, which asynchronously triggers the creation of a third type of entity. It all works perfectly, and the storage processes are beautifully decoupled.

Except for when I programmatically trigger a lot (f.e. 1000) of signals in a for-loop. Depending on my `AsynchronousPool` size, after processing signals (quite fast) in the amount of about half of that size, the application completely freezes for up to some minutes. Then it resumes, to process about the same amount of signals, quite fast, before freezing again.

I have been playing around with `AsynchronousPool` settings for the last half hour. Setting it to 2000, for instance, will easily make all my signals be processed at once, without any freezes. But the system isn't sane either, after that. Triggering another 1000 signals, resulted in them being created allright, but the entire creation of derived data never happened.

Now I am completely at a loss as to what to do. I can of course get rid of all those asynchronous events and implement some sort of queue myself, but I always thought the point of an EE container was to relieve me of such tedium. Asynchronous EJB events should already bring their own queue mechanism. One which should not freeze as soon as the queue is too full.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have now tried it with 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT. It behaves a little bit differently: It still doesn't work, but I do get an exception:

```
Aug 01, 2013 3:12:31 PM org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil handleSystemException
SEVERE: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: fail to allocate internal resource to execute the target task
javax.ejb.EJBException: fail to allocate internal resource to execute the target task
    at org.apache.openejb.async.AsynchronousPool.invoke(AsynchronousPool.java:81)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:240)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:303)
    at <<... my code ...>>
    ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Timeout waiting for executor slot: waited 30 seconds
    at org.apache.openejb.util.executor.OfferRejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(OfferRejectedExecutionHandler.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
    at org.apache.openejb.async.AsynchronousPool.invoke(AsynchronousPool.java:75)
    ... 38 more
```

It is as though TomEE would not do ANY queueing of operations. If no thread is free to process in the moment of the call, tough luck. Surely, this cannot be intended..?

**UPDATE 2:**

Okay, I seem to have stumbled upon a semi-solution: Setting the `AsynchronousPool.QueueSize` property to maxint solves the freeze. But questions remain: Why is the QueueSize so limited in the first place, and, more worryingly: Why would this block the entire application? If the queue is full, it blocks, but as soon as a task is taken from it, another should pop in, right? The queue appears to be blocked until it is completely empty again.

**UPDATE 3:**

For anyone who wants to have a go: http://github.com/JanDoerrenhaus/tomeefreezetestcase

**UPDATE 4:**

As it turns out, increasing the queue size does NOT solve the problem, it merely delays it. The problem remains the same: Too many asynchronous operations at once, and TomEE chockes so bad, that it cannot even undeploy the application on termination anymore.

So far, my diagnosis is that the task cleanup does not work properly. My tasks are all very small and fast (see the [test case on github](http://github.com/JanDoerrenhaus/tomeefreezetestcase)). I was already afraid that it would be OpenJPA or HSQLDB slowing down on too many concurrent calls, but I commented out all `em.persist` calls, and the problem remained the same. So if my tasks are quite small and fast, but still manage to block out TomEE so bad that it could not get any further task in after 30 seconds (`javax.ejb.EJBException: fail to allocate internal resource to execute the target task`), I would imagine that completed tasks linger, clogging up the pipe, so to speak.

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you done a thread-dump of the JVM just before it freezes?

Comment: i had the same issue, removing  @Asynchronous from the EventDispatcher helped, i can't remember why the eventdispatcher has been async too

Comment: @wutzebaer Well yes, that will solve the issue, since it just removes all the thread pooling and everything that caused problems. The idea was to have the handling of the event not block the initial request.

Comment: but isn't the observer function still async?

Comment: @wutzebaer Yes, but without the dispatcher method being async, triggering all the event handlers would still be sync. Might not be that much of an impact, agreed. Either way, making both async should just work, in my book, without any weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically BlockingQueues use locks to ensure the consistency of data and avoid data loss, so in too highly concurrent environment it will reject a lot of tasks (your case).

You can play on trunk with the RejectedExecutionHandler implementation to retry to offer the task. One implementation can be:

```
new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(final Runnable r, final ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (executor.getQueue().offer(r)) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    // no-op
                }
            }
            throw new RejectedExecutionException();
        }
    }
```

It even works better with random sleep (between min and max).

The idea is basically: if the queue is full, wait some short time to reduce the concurrency.

Comment: Thank you ever so much :-) Could something like that handler possibly find its way into TomEE itself, too?

Answer (score 1):

configurable through WEB-INF/application.properties https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1012